# Fade effect in Navigation drawer header

Tags: android

I have been working in an app where i need to include Navigation Drawer and bottom navigation.

I coded like below following androidhive tutorials.

```
appbarhome.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context="com.app.standardcoldpressoil.Activity.HomeActivity">

        <include layout="@layout/content_home" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.app.standardcoldpressoil.Activity.HomeActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_home">

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

But i am getting the header of navigation header faded. I have attached the screenshot of my screen.

I need Actionbar to display fragment name, so i added code in my activity like,

```
ActionBar toolbar;
 toolbar = getSupportActionBar();
        toolbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

      /*  BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);*/

        toolbar.setTitle("Shop");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. It will help for my better understanding !

[image]

nav_header_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:src="@drawable/app_logo" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="Welcome Ram"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ramjay@gmail.com"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hint: you have to use [onDrawerSlide](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.DrawerListener.html#onDrawerSlide(android.view.View, float))

Comment: Post your `nav_header_home` layout here please

Comment: @rom4ek I have included my nav_header_home.xml in my question.

Comment: I guess the culprit is `android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"`. Did you try to remove that line?

Comment: Just try android studio NavigationDrawerActivity, It may help you to solve your problem.

Comment: Hey, I can see that you're having a bad time with drawables. Get some drawables here: http://materialdesignicons.com/. Just download the Android 5.x packages and extract to your res folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The faded gap is because of the `android:fitsSystemWindows` property and the system is trying to compensate for fitting the `DrawerLayout` as per that. In order to remove the gap, all you need to do is to make the `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`for your `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` in `activity_home.xml` and also change `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"` for your `android.support.design.widget.NavigationView` in the same xml.

Your New activity_home.xml should be something like this:

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" 
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

---

This should remove the gap. Enjoy..